# Why does "import rpy2" works but "import rpy2.robjects" raises Error?

Tags: python, r, python-import, rpy2

I have checked similar errors on this issue on stackoverflow, none really address the error I am receiving.

When I import:

```
import rpy2
```

There are no issues. Yet, when I try

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
```

I get `RRuntimeError: Error in !value : invalid argument type.`

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: The title of the post and the body do not match. Please fix as we cant understand what is going wrong..

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating

```
import rpy2
```

only imports the top-level package into Python. There is no side effect. Evaluating

```
import rpy2.robjects
```

will do the following things:

1. dynamically load the shared C library `Rlib`
2. set callbacks
3. initialize an embedded R
4. bind R objects (e.g., the "base" and "global" environments) to Python objects
5. may be perform additional setup tasks requiring the evaluation of R code

The error message you are receiving indicates that it originates from R (because it is an `RRuntimeException`). I don't remember ever seeing the one your are reporting though. You will need to share a more complete traceback to hope receive more details though. The traceback will indicate where the error occurs in `rpy2`.